# Why is this timeout blocking my program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

So, I'm using node and "[onoff](https://github.com/fivdi/onoff)" to program a relay connected to my GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi. The program is pretty simple, it should turn on / off a relay based on specified time constraints. A simple example would be : *3s ON and then 7s OFF.*

I'm using the '[nanotimer](https://github.com/Krb686/nanotimer)' package to set timeouts, and have defined functions to run when the timeout happens. The first timeout `hiddenTimer` calls the second `showTimer` and then complets.

The problem arises, when I add in a button listener. The listener works and fires when I'm clicking the button outside of the `function startProgram();` but when the function is running, and we are waiting for a timeout, for example if we are waiting 7s for the hiddenTimer to fire, the program won't register button clicks. I want the button to be able to cancel the timer. Can anybody explain why it blocks?

I also tried migrating it out to a `child_process`, calling spawn. But it behaves the same.

Here is the code :

```
// THE LIBRARY USED TO CONTROL THE GPIO PINS
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
// OUR OUT-PIN FOR THE RELAY-POWER
var masterPin = new Gpio(14,'out');
// OUR INPUT FOR THE RESET BUTTON
var resetBtn = new Gpio(4,'in','both');
//  TIMER
var nanoTimer = require('nanotimer');
var hiddenTimer = new nanoTimer();
var visibleTimer = new nanoTimer();

// READ CONFIG
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('programs.json', 'utf8'));
var currentProgram = obj.programs[8];


resetBtn.watch(function(err, value) {
  console.log('RESET');
});


start(currentProgram);

function start(program) {
    // Deals with pre-delay
    if(program.hidden != 0) {
      hideTarget();
      hiddenTimer.setTimeout(preDelay, '', program.hidden); // Program.hidden = time in ms
    }

    function preDelay() {
      showTarget();
      visibleTimer.setTimeout(postDelay,'',program.visible) // Program.visible = time in ms

    }
    function postDelay() {
      hideTarget();
    }

}

function hideTarget () {
  masterPin.writeSync(0);  // POWER ON - HIDDEN
  console.log("HIDE");
}

function showTarget () {
  masterPin.writeSync(1);  // POWER OFF - VISIBLE
  console.log("SHOW");

}
```

Comment: Did you try using normal `setTimeout()`?

Comment: No, actually setTimeout() does not work either. It works before I start the start(); and after. But not inbetween.

Comment: Aaand, I'm stupid. I wired the button wrong. It only triggered WHEN the relay was active, because it took power from the same GPIO that the relay, thus "emulating" that the problem appeared from the timeout, but actually it was because the button did not register anything, because there where nothing to register because it did not have any power.